# How many ways are there to park cars and motorcycles in a parking lot with 100 spaces?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How many ways are there to park cars and motorcycles in a parking lot with 100 spaces, ordered in a row, knowing that a car occupies two spaces and a motorcyle occupies one? (all spaces must be occupied)

All cars and motorcycles are considered equal. When they are parked does not matter, where they are does

I'm trying to build this as a recurrence relation. For small numbers it looks like a Fibonacci sequence, but it's not obvious to me how the number of ways for $n $ 
spaces builds up on $(n-1)$ and $(n-2)$ spaces

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that the spaces are arranged in a row?

Comment: Also we need to know what is meant by "ways". What constitutes one "way" and distinguishes it from a different "way"? Does order count? Does the sequence of single and double spaces count or just the number of each type?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. Editing now

Comment: Ah so we are merely counting the non-negative solutions to $2x+y=n$. Is that correct?

Comment: I thought by order you meant order in time (as in, when they are parked). No, order does matter in the row

Comment: That makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ denote the number of cars and $y$ the number of motorcycles in a configuration. Then we have the condition:
$$
2x+y=n
$$
where $x,y\geq 0$. This has solutions $x=0,1,...,\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and $y=n-2x$. For each such solution there will be
$$
\binom{x+y}{x}=\frac{(x+y)!}{x!y!}
$$
ways to distribute the sequence of $x$ cars among $x+y$ vehicles. Hence the figure becomes
$$
P(n)=\sum_{x=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-x}{x}
$$
since $y=n-2x$ implies $x+y=n-x$. Perhaps this can be expressed in some different form which is more neat.

---

Heureka! It is indeed the Fibonacci sequence:
$$
P(n)=P(n-1)+P(n-2)
$$
Since you can form all new configurations ending in a motorcycle by adding a motorcycle to the end of one of the $(n-1)$-configs, and similarly all ending in a car by adding a car to the end of one of the $(n-2)$-configs. Those two are necessarily distinct because they end in a different kind of vehicle. Hence we just add them together.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try working with this and see where I can get

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bx%3D0%7D%5E50+(50-x)+choose+x) says 20365011074.

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio: See my update. I just proved your point about the Fibonacci-approach.