# counting with recurrence Car and Motorcycle

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

A bunch of motorcycles and SUVs want to parallel park on a street. The street can t n motorcycles, but SUVs take up three motorcycle spaces. **Let A(n) be the number of arrangements of cars and motorcycles on a street that fits n motorcycles.** For example, A(5) = 4 because there are four ways to park vehicles on a street with ve motorcycle spaces. If M stands for motorcycle,
and C stands for car, then the four arrangements are: MMC, MCM, CMM, and MMMMM. Write a recurrence for A(n).

My attempt is: 
since if the first vehicle is a  motorcycle, then it is (n-1) spot left; on the other hand, if the first vehicle is a car, then it is (n-3) spot left. Therefore, we have a(n)=a(n-1)+a(n-3) with a(0)=1(because there is one way to park when there is no spot. ) a(1)=1(since there is only one spot, so there is only one way) a(2)=1(since there can not fit a car, we count parking the motorcycles as the same way, which is one)
Please check my reasoning because I could have mess up with it, but still got it right.

Moreover, if my reasonings and attempt is good. I compared with the solution, which is a(n) = a(n - 1) + a(n - 3); with a(1) = 1; a(2) = 1; a(3) = 2.
They are almost the same. **My thinking based on the solution**, a(1) is only one way to park one motorcycle and a(2) = 1 since there can only part motorcycle. a(3)=2 since we can part motorcycle(count as 1) and car(count as 1) now.

which one is correct?  Thank you.

Comment: They are essentially equivalent (and correct), so there is no question to be asked here.

Comment: if they are the same. Is my reasoning is correct thought for the given solution?  thank you.

Comment: Your answer is ok, it's basically what I asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496981/how-many-ways-are-there-to-park-cars-and-motorcycles-in-a-parking-lot-with-100-s